# Generate Random numbers for multiple block call

Tags: magento2, blocks, php-7.2

I am trying to implement custom flash toy for website. To do this I have created custom module.

In custom module, I have created a block class.  Block class contain the function to generate the Random digits.

```
Here is my block's Class Name:  WM_Jackson/Block/Index/Index
```

Random Id generator code in block:

```
/**
 * generate random number for player
 *
 * @return int
 */

public function playeridGenerator()
{   
     $ran = rand(10, 999999);
    return $ran;
}
```

This rando Id generator code works fine when I call my block in cms page using below code:

```
{{block class="WM\Jackson\Block\Index\Index" template="WM_Jackson::flash_elem.phtml" }}
```

But when I add multiple blocks on the same page, it generates the duplicate ids for all the blocks.

for example if I add block code 3 times, It shows flash player 3 times but it shows same id for 3players. Hence when user try to interact with Flash show, only first player works.

```
  {{block class="WM\Jackson\Block\Index\Index" template="WM_Jackson::flash_elem.phtml" }}
  {{block class="WM\Jackson\Block\Index\Index" template="WM_Jackson::flash_elem.phtml" }}
  {{block class="WM\Jackson\Block\Index\Index" template="WM_Jackson::flash_elem.phtml" }}
```

Above code renders output 3 times but block function **playeridGenerator()** is generating same number 3 times.

How can I generate Random numbers when calling blocks multiple times?  Is there any native library in magento for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happen for Full page.

I suggest that Use [Private content concept](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)  or Call An **Ajax post request** to get content of this three block content. As Post request and  private content request are non-cache request at magento 2.

Also, You can put block name

```
{{block class="WM\Jackson\Block\Index\Index" template="WM_Jackson::flash_elem.phtml" **name="jackson.flash.one"** }}
  {{block class="WM\Jackson\Block\Index\Index" template="WM_Jackson::flash_elem.phtml" **name="jackson.flash.two"** }}
  {{block class="WM\Jackson\Block\Index\Index" template="WM_Jackson::flash_elem.phtml" **name="jackson.flash.two"** }}
```

For generate  randon string or number use

```
\Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom
```

See https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-generate-random-string-or-number-in-magento-2/